# How to create symbolic links to all files (class of files) in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I would like to create symbolic links (`ln -s`) to all files (or a class of files, e.g. ending with `.bar`) in a certain directory. 
Say I'm in the cwd and type `ls ../source/*.bar` gives me

```
foo.bar
baz.bar
```

how can I pass the parameter list to `ln -s` that it finally resolves to

```
ln -s ../source/foo.bar
ln -s ../source/baz.bar
```

Of course I know I can write a bash script, but there should be something simpler involving `xargs` or so since it seems to be a common task - at least for me.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`ln` does take multiple arguments, but don't forget to give a target directory in that case.

So, in your example `.` is the target directory, so it should be as easy as

```
ln -s ../source/*.bar .
```

From `man ln`; the command above uses the 3rd form:

```
ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

> - In  the  1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.
> - In       the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.
> - In the 3rd  and  4th  forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are no files `*.bar`. It will create a link with the name `"*.bar"`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Nimrod: That's true, but you can tell _bash_ that you want it to report an error instead via `shopt -s failglob`; see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216227/33390 (The equivalent in _zsh_ is `setopt nomatch`, which is turned on by default)

Comment: For the failure reporting, what's the equivalent for csh or generically sh for any shell?

Answer (score 10):

You can try recursively either with using globstar (bash/zsh set by: `shopt -s globstar`):

```
ls -vs ../**/*.bar .
```

<sup>Note: Added `-v` for verbose.</sup>

Or if the list is too long, using `find` utility:

```
find .. -name \*.bar -exec ln -vs "{}" dest/ ';'
```

This will create links in `dest/`, or change it to `.` for current folder.

Comment: The second one is the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use `find`

```
certainDir="/path/to/dir"
find -name "*.bar" -exec ln -s {} "$certainDir" \;
```

Also, remember to use *full paths* (where possible) with symlinks.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it `find $certainDir -name "*.bar" -exec ln -s {} \;`? And why should I use full paths? I find it quite convenient to know that links stay intact when I move a directory tree around wihch has some internal links.

Comment: That depends where you want to symlink the directories. And I can't remember why full paths are a good idea, it might have been for hard links but I burned that into my mind for a reason. Hmmm.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is great. Since mpy's answer is the simpler solution to the question, the point goes to him/her. I would accept both answers, if I could.

Answer (score 5):

`cp` with `-s` option can create a soft links (or `-l` for hard links).

From current directory can by used like this:

```bsh
$ cp -s ../path/with/scripts/* .
```

In your case it will be like this:

```bsh
$ cp -s ../source/*.bar .
```

Comment: Found an interesting related post on symlinks with cp: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46047/create-symbolic-links-with-wildcards